# Using Butter Knife in Custom BaseAdapter SubClass Results in "Unable to inject views" error

Tags: java, android, annotations, baseadapter, butterknife

I'm attempting to use Butter Knife to simplify creation of a custom BaseAdapter class.  I'm following the example here: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ under the "Another use is simplifying the view holder pattern inside of a list adapter." section.   Unfortunately, I am getting an "Unable to inject views" error each time the ViewHolder is created for each item in the list.

Here is my code:

```
public class ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayListNames.size();
}

@Override
public Name getItem(int iPosition) {
    return arrayListNames.get(iPosition);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int iID) {
    return 0;
}

LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<Name> arrayListNames = new ArrayList<Name>();
static Context context;
Activity activity;

public ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Name> names, Activity activity) {
    arrayListNames = names;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}



static class ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    @InjectView(R.id.textViewFullName) TextView textViewFullName;
    @InjectView(R.id.imageButtonDeleteName) TextView imageButtonDeleteName;
    @OnClick(R.id.imageButtonDeleteName)
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ((NameActivity)context).DeleteUser((Name)view.getTag());
    }

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
    }
}

@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView != null) {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_name, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    viewHolder.textViewFullName.setText(((Name)getItem(position)).GetFullName());
    L.l("ArrayAdapterName", ((Name)getItem(position)).GetID() + " inserted in list | position = " + position);
    viewHolder.imageButtonDeleteName.setTag((Name)getItem(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

The error happens at the "ButterKnife.Inject(this, view);" line.  It also happens each time the view holder is created for each item I am putting in the list.  Does anybody know how to make this work the way it should?

In reply to Jake Wharton's comment
First, let me say thank you for developing this tool.  It has made android development much more enjoyable than it was when I first started.

Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
05-04 07:29:01.991    2424-2424/com.murach.databasehomework E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject views for com.murach.databasehomework.ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter$ViewHolder@52700878
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:221)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:184)
            at com.murach.databasehomework.ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter.java:59)
            at com.murach.databasehomework.ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter.getView(ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter.java:70)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:216)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:184)
            at com.murach.databasehomework.ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter.java:59)
            at com.murach.databasehomework.ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter.getView(ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter.java:70)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
            at com.murach.databasehomework.ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter$ViewHolder$$ViewInjector.inject(ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter$ViewHolder$$ViewInjector.java:13)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:216)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:184)
            at com.murach.databasehomework.ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter.java:59)
            at com.murach.databasehomework.ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter.getView(ButterknifeCustomBaseAdapter.java:70)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Paste the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Check if your `@InjectView`s has correct type. I've used `ImageView` instead of `LinearLayout`. That might be your problem too.

**Update:**

Make sure you are not using ButterKnife's `@OnItemClick(R.id.non_list_view)` with a non `ListView`. I was using it for a `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` which was causing following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject views for MyFragment{... id=.... android:switcher:...}
```

Comment: That was it.  I can't believe I missed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Also check if you are inflating correct `R.layout.` file. If not - necessary views are not found and this error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with ButterKnife, but the reason was that I was inflating my fragment with the wrong layout.

(*I know the question was already answered, but I decided to post my solution in case someone had the same issue*)

Comment: This is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

Those who are still looking it happens if you are trying to bind wrong View type from XML in Java file it .

For example

You have TextView with id result

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:text="Calculator"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
```

And you try to bind it with Button in java file

> @BindView(R.id.result)
>       Button  result;

It gone crash you app.

**Butterknife will throw exception for illegal casting of views as Unable to Inject View Error**

Answer (score 1):

For me it turned out that the `ViewBinder` was not correctly refreshed. **A clean project-build solved this issue.**