# Butter Knife - Unable to bind views for Fragment

Tags: android, butterknife

I get an exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for Fragment on ButterKnife.bind(this, view). The code is as shown below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    BindData();

    return view;
}
```

Comment: please show us whole fragment that you are using ButterKnife with and also exact, whole, runtime exception you get.

Comment: I use just like this and have no problem, something is missing. Show us the exception and what BindData() is doing.

Comment: ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(), view);
just replace this line with yours

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have a look on this answer
[Using Butter Knife in Custom BaseAdapter SubClass Results in "Unable to inject views" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448925/using-butter-knife-in-custom-baseadapter-subclass-results-in-unable-to-inject-v)

looks like you must mistake on some view type or id

Comment: Thank you, i rechecked my code and apparently the mistake was with the view type

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate answer. Anyway my problem (and probably yours too) is:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```

Then the ImageView is bound to another class, for example an ImageButton

```
@Bind(R.id.imageView)
ImageButton notAnImageButton
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because of wrong data type of bind view